# Controlling Excel time format input/output

Tags: excel, time-format

**Background:** I have been officiating our local jogging events for about ten years now. I am responsible for handling the data of the participants (name, sporting club, bib number) split into their categories (age bracket+gender, distance). The main task is collecting their times, and processing that data (sorting the runners within their category etc). I can handle this with Excel mostly fine.

**Problem:** What is the ideal time format for entering the race times of the participants? The times are either in the format `mm:ss` or (for slower runners and/or longer distances) `h:mm:ss`. Excel doesn't seem to have a built-in format where the hours field is optional. For optimizing my workflow ideally I would like to have a cell format such that the input
`47:12` is to be interpreted as 47 minutes and 12 seconds, and the input `1:09:38` is to be interpreted as 1hr 9 minutes and 38 seconds. However, Excel, with the best fitting cell format that I found, will insist that the input `47:12` means 47 hours and 12 minutes. For times exceeding 1 hour I would input `1:03:00` if I meant that the seconds field is to be left with value zero.

> How to make Excel realize that when the format can handle up to three numbers as inputs, it would, when given only two numbers, move them towards the **end**?

**Thinking:** I "can" key in 47 minutes and 12 seconds as `0:47:12` all right. But because most of the times are under 1 hour, that is partly wasted effort. Also, using such a format the data is displayed on the screen together with that superfluous `0:`. What's worse (IIRC) those leading zeros
also appear in the printed versions, which is strange (insulting even) in a shorter distance for junior participants.

**My hack:** I enter the times as general numbers in the `mm,ss` format (in these parts a comma serves as a decimal separator). Excel can sort those as numbers just fine. I then duplicate the data of that sorted column to another "printable" version (formatted as text), where the data is just copied, but I correct the times exceeding 60 minutes by hand. This works just fine as long as I'm not in a hurry (our event is not exactly Boston Marathon, say, less than 200 participants), and remember to hide the column that is not supposed to be printed. This is kludgy, and there have been accidents, when other officials have been rushing me to get the results printed.

Comment: does time over an hour get record as `hhmm,ss`?

Comment: one option you could look at is having 1 sheet for data entry of all runners, and then subsequent sheets that automatically strip the data into printable format, and filter it to just what you are looking for.  Ie one sheet for youth, one sheet for seniors, even break it up by course A, B, and C if desired.

Comment: @ForwardEd Using my hack I record it as `mmm,ss` So I record 1hr 7min 12 s as `67,12`. If it makes life easier, I can record it as `hhmm,ss' because that won't affect the sorting. Nor do I need to calculate time differences, average speeds and such. I will be happy with a solution as long as sorting and output formatting go as planned.

Comment: Yup, I already have separate sheets for juniors, joggers, and male/female racers. AND a master sheet (sorted by bib number) for entering the times. I use a column in my master sheet to indicate the category (=course+gender+ age bracket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create a format where the hour-field **is** optional. It works with a conditional format. First you format your cells as standard, so you get the times as comma-values. After that you create a conditional format for these cells, which has two rules:

1. if cellvalue > 0.04166667 format hh:mm:ss
2. if cellvalue < 0.04166666 format mm:ss

Result:
`47:12`
`01:09:38`
`01:00:00`

So you get what you really want and you can use the original values for sorting and so on.

**EDIT:**

**For the input** you need four additional columns. You enter the times as you want, e.g. 47:12 and 1:09:38. In the next three columns you split these values in hour, minute and second, whereby the interpretation limit is 3 hours (03:00), which is 0.125.

So, these are the formulas for the split columns (your input is in B1):

Hours: `=IF(B1>0.125,0,HOUR(B1))`
Minutes: `=IF(B1>0.125,INT(B1)*24+HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1))`
Seconds: `=IF(B1>0.125,MINUTE(B1),SECOND(B1))`

And finally, you put all values togehter in the forth column:

`=TIME(C1,D1,E1)`

and use the conditional format above.

Comment: meaning that data entry must include `0:47:12` for times less than 1 hour?

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, as excel always treats inputs of the form "nn:nn" as "hh:mm". You can't change this behaviour with a conditinal format.

Comment: Thanks. So this controls the display/output (need to test it), but does not help with my input problem.

Comment: I should probably study `cellvalue` and related functions. Because the times in my data are never less than 3 minutes nor over three hours, may I can insert a step that divides that numerical value by 60 whenever it exceeds 3 hours?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I added a proposal for the input of the times.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be entering your data as

```
`mmm,ss`
```

where the comma is the decimal point, then you can convert it to "Excel Time" with the simple formula:

```
=DOLLARDE(A1,60)/1440
```

Format the result as you wish.

If you want everything displayed as `h:mm:ss` then use that as your custom format (Format > Cells > Number > Custom Type:...)

If you want `h` to be displayed only with values of 60 minutes or greater, then use

```
[<0.0416666666666667]mm:ss;h:mm:ss
```

for your cell's custom format.

Beware that seconds must be entered with two digits always.  In other words

```
6,2   will translate to 6 min 20 sec.
6,02  will translate to 6 min  2 sec
```

Comment: nice one Ron, I was not aware you could put a constraint on custom formatting like < or >.  very cool!

Comment: @Forwarded You can also do colors based on the conditions.  Of course, `Conditional Formatting` is more flexible, but this older method still has its uses.  Was used a lot more before CF was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

I really like IQV's answer above, but as pointed out in the comment section, the leading zero will be required for the data entry side.  If for whatever reason this is not acceptable you can use the following ugly formula to convert your time entered in your usual method of mm,ss to hh:mm:ss with the hh: being displayed as required.  Unfortunately it converts the whole thing to text which means you can no longer perform math operations on it.

```
=IF(FIND(".",MOD(D2,60)&".")=2,"0","")&MOD(D2,60)
```

and since you use , as your decimal separator the formula would become:

```
IF(FIND(",",MOD(D2,60)&",")=2,"0","")&MOD(D2,60)
```

If you use ; as your list separator then your formula becomes

```
IF(FIND(",";MOD(D2;60)&",")=2;"0";"")&MOD(D2;60)
```

There are probably some cleaner formulas, but that will get you started.  Just replace D2 with the location where your time is stored.

[image]

Again I still prefer IQV's answer as you can do much more with the time information when its stored as a number and not text.

### Option 2

lets say you change your data storage method to hhmm,ss in cell D6.  you could rip apart the information and reassemble it in a display friendly version as follows.

```
=IF(FIND(".",D6)<=3,LEFT(D6,2)&":"&RIGHT(D6,LEN(D6)-FIND(".",D6)),LEFT(D6,FIND(".",D6)-3)&":"&MID(D6,FIND(".",D6)-2,2)&":"&RIGHT(D6,LEN(D6)-FIND(".",D6)))
```

you will need to substitute your list separator for the , and then substitute a coma for the decimal.

[image: POC2]

Comment: Thanks. I need to play with the idea. It actually should help, because I can input the entries as numbers, and then convert them to text automatically (not by hand as I do now).

Comment: i you went the route of storing a time like `1:27:34` as `127,34` instead of `87,34`, you could use the following process.  check the length to see if it is 2 or more digits in front of the , if so you would break it apart using `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT` and put it all together in an if statement.

Comment: I did store it as `87,34`. That is not a problem.

Comment: actually one small problem...a time of 60.00 does not display the way you want.  its a special case that can be handles separately though.  hrmm I have to dash to work, but the case of ending in 0 seconds needs to be adjusted...would you ever record more than 1 second accuracy?  ie, 89,125